# Excel formula - Calculating the average time for all of the latest time for each day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of dates/Time. What I want to do is find the average of the latest time for each day. Can someone help me with the formula?

Here's an example:

6/23/2016 14:42:00
6/23/2016 4:20:00
8/30/2016 9:20:00
8/30/2016 19:20:00
8/31/2016 13:20:00
8/31/2016 16:20:00
9/1/2016 13:20:00
9/1/2016 19:20:00

It should then be calculating the average time of "6/23/2016 14:42:00", "8/30/2016 19:20:00", "8/31/2016 16:20:00" and "9/1/2016 19:20:00".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know if I could do it with formulae alone (someone maybe could but it looks quite difficult). It should be fine with VBA if that would work for you?

Comment: What would the result of your computation be?

Comment: I suggest you use Power Query or Power Pivot.  You can split the dates and times; group by dates; take the maximum time for each of the dates, and then, on the returned table, compute the average of the returned times (if that is what you mean by average); or compute the average of the returned date/time stamps, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Ron - The result would be the average of 14:42:00, 19:20:00, 16:20:00, 19:20:00 which comes out to 17:25:30

Answer (score 0):

Hard solution would look like this:

Get distinct dates first.
This is done by typing formula `=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)`, assuming that your values are in column A.

Now copy the column with results into another column using **Paste Values**.

After that you should remove duplicates from the column you pasted your values in and next to it insert **Array Formula**

```
=MAX(IF(criteria_range=criteria,value_range))
```

All you have to do now is run an average on it.

Now, if you are to use it more than once, just record a macro using the above steps.

*Array formula is applied by using **Ctrl**+**Shift****+Enter** (Instead of regular **Enter**)